# OpenERP hide top menu items

Tags: odoo

Is there a way to hide the top menu items on specific groups without restricting objects permissions in security files?
I created a module which uses functionalities from multiple modules and I put the corresponding menus in my module, so I don't need all the top menus anymore.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide top menu of all modules, then you have to overwrite the exiting menu of all modules in you modules and assign an another group to these menus, so when you give this group to user in access rigths then only he can see the other top menu

hope this will help

Comment: and how to do that? I tried to define a menu item with the same id and overwrite the groups on it but doesn't work.

Comment: hi qwerty, what you done is correct, but you miss one thing you have to also overwright all childs of purchase menu and do same thing with the menu, hope it clear now